# I don't know what's bad in my SQL (in Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm doing a test database for a cruise company. The fact is that I made the code in an online IDE (db-fiddle), but when it comes to putting it in  Oracle SQL Developer I get this error in almost all the tables.

[image: Oracle SQL Developer]

```sql
create table CLIENT (
    DNI varchar(9),
    Nombre varchar(20) not null,
    Fecha_nacimiento date not null,
    CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY (DNI)
);

create table RUTA (
    Estacion varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT ruta_pk PRIMARY KEY (Estacion)
);

create table RESERVA (
    ID_Reserva int(10),
    Precios int(10) not null,
    Horario_comedor varchar(20) not null,
    Fecha date not null,
    Excursiones_opcionales varchar(50) not null,
    Actividades_extra varchar(50) not null,
    DNI varchar(9) not null,
    Estacion varchar(30) not null, 
    CONSTRAINT reserva_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID_Reserva),
    CONSTRAINT reserva_client_fk FOREIGN KEY (DNI)
    references CLIENT (DNI),
    CONSTRAINT reserva_ruta_fk FOREIGN KEY (Estacion)
    references RUTA (Estacion)
);
-- Tabla para almacenar la relación N:N entre cliente y reserva

create table CHECKIN (
    DNI varchar(9),
    ID_Reserva int(10),
    CONSTRAINT checkin_pk PRIMARY KEY (DNI, ID_reserva),
    CONSTRAINT check_client_fk FOREIGN KEY (DNI)
    references CLIENT (DNI),
    CONSTRAINT check_reserva_fk FOREIGN KEY (ID_Reserva)
    references RESERVA (ID_Reserva)
);

create table PUERTO (
    ID_Puerto int(10),
    Localidad varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT puerto_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID_Puerto)
);

create table LISTA_PUERTOS (
    Estacion varchar(30),
    ID_Puerto int(10),
    Situacion varchar(20) not null,
    ID_Lista int(10), 
    CONSTRAINT lista_puertos_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID_Lista),
    CONSTRAINT estacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (Estacion)
    references RUTA (Estacion),
    CONSTRAINT puerto_fk FOREIGN KEY (ID_Puerto)
    references PUERTO (ID_Puerto)
);
```

Comment: in the image, I  can see that comma is missing for the last 2 sentences of the query. I hope this is not the issue.

Comment: The error in the image is for a table which isn't included in your posted code.

Comment: As I recall DB Fiddle doesn't support  Oracle explicitly. Writing SQL on a different platform from your actual target is not a good idea, because all RDBMS products have subtle (and not so subtle) differences in syntax. Use SQL Fiddle - if it is up - or Oracle's own LiveSQL, which is free but requires a login.

Answer (score 3):

The issue in in the `INT(10)` type, which should be edited into `NUMBER(10)`, according to [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9401BC04-81C4-4CD5-99E7-C5E25C83F608).

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(
    DNI                                     VARCHAR(9),
    Nombre                                  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Fecha_nacimiento                        DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT client_pk PRIMARY KEY(DNI)
);

CREATE TABLE RUTA
(
    Estacion                                VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT ruta_pk PRIMARY KEY(Estacion)
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVA
(
    ID_Reserva                              NUMBER(10),
    Precios                                 NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    Horario_comedor                         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Fecha                                   DATE NOT NULL,
    Excursiones_opcionales                  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Actividades_extra                       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DNI                                     VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Estacion                                VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT reserva_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID_Reserva),
    CONSTRAINT reserva_client_fk FOREIGN KEY(DNI) REFERENCES CLIENT(DNI),
    CONSTRAINT reserva_ruta_fk FOREIGN KEY(Estacion) REFERENCES RUTA(Estacion)
);

-- Tabla para almacenar la relación N:N entre cliente y reserva

CREATE TABLE CHECKIN
(
    DNI                                     VARCHAR(9),
    ID_Reserva                              NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT checkin_pk PRIMARY KEY(DNI, ID_reserva),
    CONSTRAINT check_client_fk FOREIGN KEY(DNI) REFERENCES CLIENT(DNI),
    CONSTRAINT check_reserva_fk FOREIGN KEY(ID_Reserva) REFERENCES RESERVA(ID_Reserva)
);

CREATE TABLE PUERTO
(
    ID_Puerto                               NUMBER(10),
    Localidad                               VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT puerto_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID_Puerto)
);

CREATE TABLE LISTA_PUERTOS
(
    Estacion                                VARCHAR(30),
    ID_Puerto                               NUMBER(10),
    Situacion                               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ID_Lista                                NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT lista_puertos_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID_Lista),
    CONSTRAINT estacion_fk FOREIGN KEY(Estacion) REFERENCES RUTA(Estacion),
    CONSTRAINT puerto_fk FOREIGN KEY(ID_Puerto) REFERENCES PUERTO(ID_Puerto)
);
```

Comment: Additionally, although VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 are currently synonyms, Oracle recommend using VARCHAR2 - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822